# No se carga fichero log ni mensaje en Consola en Maven

Tags: java, maven, log4j

Estoy implantando `log4j.jar` en mi proyecto maven y voy a utilizar el fichero `log4j.properties` que se encuentra en en `src/main/resource`.
La clase que ejecuta es la siguiente:

```
public class Log4jInit extends HttpServlet{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static Logger log = null;

@Override
public void init(){

    String file = getInitParameter(Constantes.LOG4JINIT);


    if(file != null){

        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
        log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jInit.class);
        log.info("prueba");
    }
}

 @Override
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
 }
```

}

El fichero `log4j.properties` contiene lo siguiente (Esta configurado para que salga en consola y tambien que se genere un fichero log):

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLA,ARCHIVO

log4j.appender.CONSOLA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLA.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.ARCHIVO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.File=/logapp85/salesforcews/salesforcews.log
log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.ARCHIVO.MaxFileSize=2MB
```

En `web.xml` tengo lo siguiente:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>es.aaa.n005.utils.Log4jInit</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

y en el `pom.xml` :

```
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/resource</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
         <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
```

El problema que tengo es que aunque en todas las clases utilizo `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;` no se me carga en la consola ni se genera el fichero
Me podríais indicar que puede faltar o que esta mal configurado? cualquier duda o aclaración decídmelo y lo veo.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: En los properties lo que veo que falta es la configuración de loggers, además de los appenders. Por otro lado no recuerdo haber tenido que configurar el servlet para levantar log4j, con poner el properties en resources, y estando el jar de log4j en el classpath es suficiente. Por las dudas, la versión actual es log4j2 fijate bien cual estás implementando porque son diferentes...

Comment: Buenas @Juan. ¿Me podrias indicar como configurar los logger y los appenders en properties? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para log4j2 fijate la sección "Configuration with Properties" en https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html